# hide safari and chrome internet results in spotlight searches

Tags: safari, google-chrome, spotlight, search

When i search for something using spotlight (CMD + SPACEBAR),  I don't want to see anything related to internet searches using safari or chrome.

Is there a way to disable spotlight from using these two programs?

In settings -> Spotlight,   I don't see a checkbox for "internet"

This is my settings so far:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which macOS, it's called either Spotlight Suggestions or Siri Suggestions.

See [Apple KB - Turn off Siri Suggestions for Spotlight on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl62db64f5/mac)

Confirmed by comments, a website in results could be a bookmark or recently visited, in which case you'd also need to uncheck 'Bookmarks & History'.

Comment: im on macOS bigsur 11.3.1.  Siri suggestions is turned off in spotlight suggestions.. If i type 'd' in spotlight, it still shows me disney.com as an autocomplete for safari...

Comment: Do you have it as a bookmark, or been there recently? That's a different checkbox.

Comment: wow, unchecking bookmarks seems to have done it... I guess apple preinstalls 'disney' as a safari bookmark on new laptops... thanks

Comment: I get web search results in Spotlight. They are not for browser bookmarks, and I have Siri Suggestions and all of Siri disabled.